# SQL Server Employee table with existing ID number

Tags: sql-server, identity

I am attempting to create an Employee table in SQL Server 2016 and I want to use EmpID as the Primary Key and Identity.  Here is what I believe to be true and my question:  When I create the Employee table with EmpID as the Primary Key and an Identity(100, 1) column, each time I add a new employee, SQL Server will auto create the EmpID starting with 100 and increment by 1 with each new employee.  What happens if I want to import a list of existing employees from another company and those employees already have an existing EmpID?  I haven't been able to figure out how I would import those employees with the existing EmpID.  If there is a way to import the employee list with the existing EmpID, will SQL Server check to make sure the EmpID's from the new list does not exist for a current employee?  Or is there some code I need to write in order to make that happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Dose EmpID column is foreign key to any other table in your database? and Do you want to import only Employee table from another database or all its related table too?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about primary keys, but about importing employees from another company and Merging it with your employee list, you have to ask these things:

1. WHY? Sure there are ways to solve this problem, but why will you merge other company employees into your company employee?
2. Other company ID structure: Most of the time, companies have different ID structure, some have 4 characters others have only numbers so on and so forth. But you have to know the differences of the companies ID Structure.

If the merging can't be avoided, then you have to tell the higher ups about the concern, and you have to tell them that you have to give the merging company new employee ID's which is a must. With this in my, simply appending your database with the new data is the solution.

Comment: I would need to merge the other company's employees in the case of an acquisition, but that raises another question: The EmpID would need to be a unique number for each employee.  Would there be a better way to allow for the importing of an acquired company's employee list?  Is there a way to have another column with the employee ID number which can be tested for duplicates?

Comment: You can have a foreign key and a primary key, the primary key will be the unique key for you overall table, while the foreign key will be the employee IDs. Your best bet IMO, is ask HR about this scenario because most of the time, new employees weather newly employed or acquired, are given new employee numbers by the host company.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely normal data warehousing issue where a table has data sources from multiple places. Also comes up in migration, acquisitions, etc.

There is no way to keep the existing IDs as a primary key if there are multiple people with the same ID.

In the data warehouse world we would always create a new surrogate key, which is the primary key to the table, and include the original key and a source system identifier as two attributes.

In your scenario you will probably keep the existing keys for the original company, and create new IDs for the new employees, and save the oldID in an additional column for historical use.

Either of these choices also means that as you migrate other associated data such as leave information imported from the old system, you can translate it to the new key by looking up OldID in the employee table, and finding the associated newID to associate it with when saving your lave records in the new system.

At the end of the day there is no alternative to this, as you simply cant have two employees with the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any company that migrate employees from another company and keep their existed employee id. Usually, they'll give them a new ID and keep the old one in the employee file for references uses. But they never uses the old one as an active ID ever.

Large companies usually uses serial of special identities that are already defined in the system to distinguish employees based on field, specialty..etc.

Most companies they don't do the same as large ones, but instead, they stick with one identifier, and uses dimensions as an identity. These dimensions specify areas of work for employees, projects, vendors ..etc. So, they're used in the system globally, and affected on company financial reports (which is the main point of using it).

So, what you need to do is to see the company ID sequence requirements, then, play your part on that. As depending on IDENTITY alone won't be enough for most companies. If you see that you can depend on identity alone, then use it, if not, then see if you can use dimensions as an identity (you could create five dimensions - Company, Project, Department, Area, Cost Center - it will be enough for any company).

if you used identity alone, and want to migrate, then in your insert statement do :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tableName ON
INSRT INTO tableName (columns)
...
```

this will allow you to insert inside identity column, however, doing this might require you to reset the identity to a new value, to avoid having issues. read [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you end up using dimensions, you could make the dimension and ID both primary keys, which will make sure that both are unique in the table (treated as one set).

Comment: Just be cautious with this `Large companies usually uses serial of special identities that are already defined in the system to distinguish employees based on field, specialty..etc.` While it might be true for established very old systems, Its best to avoid if its not already in place as it breaks a basic data modelling rule about hiding information inside fields.